# Spring Config is trying to open FTP connection to local filesystem

Tags: spring

I'm starting to build a Spring Config server and DO NOT WANT to put it on a GIT for now.

So I need to point all my configurations to a shared docker folder.

Here is my server POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and my server application.properties:

```
server.port=36206
spring.application.name=archimedes
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=${SEARCH_LOCATION}
```

... and the start script:

```
docker run --name archimedes --hostname=archimedes \
-v /srv/archimedes/:/archimedes \
-e SEARCH_LOCATION="file://archimedes" \
-p 36206:36206 \
-d archimedes:1.5
```

and I put all my ".properties" inside `/srv/archimedes` which is `/archimedes` inside the container.

I think it is all configuration I need to do as all sources I could find around but the error I receive when try to call `<http://myserver.com>:36206/hades/default` is :

```
2021-10-21 12:49:55.132  WARN 1 --- [io-36206-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.e.EnvironmentController        : Error getting the Environment with name=hades profiles=default label=null includeOrigin=false
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.FailedToConstructEnvironmentException: Could not construct context for config=hades profile=default label=null includeOrigin=false; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NativeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:158) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.findOne(EnvironmentEncryptorEnvironmentRepository.java:61) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.getEnvironment(EnvironmentController.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController.defaultLabel(EnvironmentController.java:108) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:485) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$614467db.defaultLabel(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IO error on loading imports from [file://archimedes/]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:89) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:121) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:240) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:227) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.applyTo(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:201) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NativeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:139) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:585) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:961) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:923) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1018) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1004) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:418) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:186) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.origin.OriginTrackedResource.getInputStream(OriginTrackedResource.java:61) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedPropertiesLoader$CharacterReader.<init>(OriginTrackedPropertiesLoader.java:203) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedPropertiesLoader.load(OriginTrackedPropertiesLoader.java:79) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedPropertiesLoader.load(OriginTrackedPropertiesLoader.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.loadProperties(PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.java:70) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.load(PropertiesPropertySourceLoader.java:49) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:54) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLoader.load(StandardConfigDataLoader.java:36) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.load(ConfigDataLoaders.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:128) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

I'm very confuse because I can see a try to open a FTP connection to the local filesystem.

Already tried `"'file://archimedes'"` and `"[file://archimedes]"` and `[file://archimedes]` in SEARCH_LOCATION but anything different of `"file://archimedes"` will give me an empty configuration.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all guys.

Found the problem: although all documentation tells me to use `file:///` in a Windows environment and `file://` in a Linux environment, this mangy dog only work after I change SEARCH_LOCATION to `file:///archimedes`.

Karma.